# Plots changing/reversing from Script when using knitr in an .rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown

When running my plots in the R script, my plots/visualizations are appearing correct. However, once I paste the code in an .rmd code chunk, the entire plot flips and its structure changes entirely.

[Messed up plot when using knitr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYwMj.png)
[plot in script/desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InECw.png)

```
ggplot(data=books_df_new)+
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x=Year,y=Rating,alpha = 0.1))+
  facet_wrap(~Genre)+
  geom_text(aes(label='The Casual Vacancy by JK Rowling (3.3)',x=2013.5,y=3.37,fontface="bold"),data=data.frame(Genre="Fiction"))+
  geom_text(aes(label='The Girl on The Train (4.1)',x=2016,y=4.15,fontface="bold"),data=data.frame(Genre="Fiction"))
```

Comment: Basically the issue is that in your "Script" plot `Rating` is a numeric whereas in the messed up "Rmd" version it is a character or factor. Most likely reason is that for the "Script" version you did some data wrangling steps which you did not include in your Rmd.